# Android (Delphi) : Clarifying remote push notifications and threads

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, push-notification, thread-safety

Something is unclear for me about push notifications (Firebase Cloud Messaging). A notification can trigger some operations, for instance, it requires GPS coordinates of the device, so the application gets the coordinates using sensors and sends them to a server. However, while this stuff, the application itself, using a timer or using GPS sensors or even responding to a user action, may have to send GPS coordinates, using the same function at the same time as the one triggered by push notification.

I guess, but maybe I'm wrong here, that push notification has its own thread so when a push notification is received, the functions called do not use the UI thread? If such a function is run from UI thread at the same time using another thread or the UI thread, a conflict can occur. So we have to use a classic mechanism to handle this, that is with Delphi use TCriticalSection object, acquire a lock, then release it?

Or if I'm wrong, the push notification runs on UI thread, blocks it, so we have to create a new thread to call the function we want to execute?

Another question is are sensors thread-safe?

And one more question, is the mobile device able to receive several notifications at the same time, or is there a kind of notification queue so notifications are received one by one?

Comment: It really depends on what the code does when notification is received. If it's sending location data to a server, it sounds like it's not even interacting with the UI. Please be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Comment: The question is note about code called by notification event, but about the notification itself, that is the call of ServiceConnection.OnReceiveNotification. Is the OneceiveNotification called by main thread or not ?

Comment: You still need to be more specific about the actual issue, if indeed there is any. As it stands, your question is very vague - what is the problem you are trying to solve? Is there one?

Comment: To answer your revised comment, please look at TFcmPushService.MessageReceivedListener in the FMX.PushNotification.Android unit. ProcessBundle calls TThread.Queue for DoReceiveNotification, so OnReceiveNotification will be called in the main thread. Having said that, your question should still reflect what the *actual* problem is, if there is any, what you have tried, and the results of that

Comment: I don't try to solve any problem and I have no issue. I just try to understand how notifications work exactly to write right and efficient code and to prevent any problem :-). I want to be sure of what I'm doing. What I've made for now is creating an anonymous thread in the procedure OnReceiveNotification. I need confirmation : Is it the right way ? It seems to be. I don't want my code blocks the main thread. But I don't want to write useless code too. So if notifications create their own threads, no need to write mines.